# svg giving random margin

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using it to make a wave animation for my website so I run into this problem where I finish my shape it giving a random margin-bottom, can anyone explain to me why it did this?

```css
.content-add-kelebihan {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.item-add-kelebihan {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.header-item-kelebihan {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card-item-kelebihan {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.280);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wave-animations-wrapper svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.deskripsi-item-kelebihan {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f16041, #faab60);
}
```

```html
<div class="content-add-kelebihan">
  <h1>TEKNOLOGI</h1>
  <p>Fitur yang disediakan oleh aplikasi ini seperti berikut ini</p>
  <div class="item-add-kelebihan">
    <div class="card-item-kelebihan">
      <div class="header-item-kelebihan">
        <i class="fas fa-robot"></i><br>
        <label>ChatBot</label>
      </div>
      <div class="wave-animations-wrapper">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
                      <path fill="#f16041" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,256L60,250.7C120,245,240,235,360,197.3C480,160,600,96,720,74.7C840,53,960,75,1080,74.7C1200,75,1320,53,1380,42.7L1440,32L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
                    </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="deskripsi-item-kelebihan">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `svg{display:block;}` to your css

Answer (score 0):

use `svg{margin:-4px}` or use `svg{display:block}` as per @enxaneta comment. Both are working fine

```css
.content-add-kelebihan {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.item-add-kelebihan {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.header-item-kelebihan {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card-item-kelebihan {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.280);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wave-animations-wrapper svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.deskripsi-item-kelebihan {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f16041, #faab60);
}

svg{margin:-4px}
```

```html
<div class="content-add-kelebihan">
  <h1>TEKNOLOGI</h1>
  <p>Fitur yang disediakan oleh aplikasi ini seperti berikut ini</p>
  <div class="item-add-kelebihan">
    <div class="card-item-kelebihan">
      <div class="header-item-kelebihan">
        <i class="fas fa-robot"></i><br>
        <label>ChatBot</label>
      </div>
      <div class="wave-animations-wrapper">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
                      <path fill="#f16041" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,256L60,250.7C120,245,240,235,360,197.3C480,160,600,96,720,74.7C840,53,960,75,1080,74.7C1200,75,1320,53,1380,42.7L1440,32L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
                    </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="deskripsi-item-kelebihan">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the svg default inline block or they have their own style? ?

Comment: @adhi_wika [refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19862230/6108882) for svg